# Amazon IAP doesn't invoke onPurchaseResponse

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I have an android app, which is using IAP. I'm sending *PurchasingManager.initiateGetUserIdRequest()* and getting the **user ID successfully** in *onGetUserIdResponse*.

After getting the response the *PurchasingManager.initiatePurchaseRequest("sku")* is invoked, but unfortunately the desired *onPurchaseResponse* seems never be called.

My applications IAP items are approved by amazon. What's the problem and how can it be solved?

Comment: Solved! The problem was the Manifest file - I have forgotten to add necessary lines in Manifest file.

Answer (score 2):

In our case, the issue ended up being that we had added the android:exported="false" flag to our Amazon IAP Response Receiver in the manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="com.amazon.inapp.purchasing.ResponseReceiver"
          android:exported="false" >
...
</receiver>
```

This prevents the Amazon purchasing application from being able to call back to your app via intents so you need to remove it.  Lesson learned...